SSH shows double shell prompt after entering a command
As you can see in the example below, the shell prompt is duplicated after I use a command.
I tried changing the PS1 to something simpler, but the same issue continues to occur:
PS1="\u@\h:\W\$ "

Notice that pressing enter on a blank line gets rid of it, but it comes back after issuing the command. Also, it doesn't always happen (intermittent).
I'm using Debian 12 on the remote machine, and SSH from cmd on Windows 10
umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$ env | less
umbrel@umbrel:~$ umbrel@umbrel:~$
umbrel@umbrel:~$

UPDATE:
Answers to questions in the response:
echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$

umbrel@umbrel:~$ ps ft
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
   4018 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
 195314 pts/1    R+     0:00  \_ ps ft

UPDATE 2:
umbrel@umbrel:~$ ps -ef | grep pts/1
umbrel      4017    4011  0 Jun18 ?        00:00:01 sshd: umbrel@pts/1
umbrel      4018    4017  0 Jun18 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
umbrel    198589    4018  0 23:20 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -ef
umbrel    198590    4018  0 23:20 pts/1    00:00:00 grep pts/1


The only way I've seen this happen is when I've accidentally got two shells running and reading input.  If you can manage to run ps or better ps ft, that should show you if there are two.  If there are two, sleep 60 is a good way to tie one up for a bit.
You might try running other commands, to see if perhaps the less is relevant.
You might running echo "$PS1" to see what PS1 is actually set to.

In this case, the problem is probably simpler.  Your prompt (like mine) is designed to put the prompt information into the window title.  The machine you are SSHing from probably does not respect those escape sequences, and just displays the text.  You should make your prompt depend on the setting of the $TERM variable.

At least for now, try just setting
PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$ '

Then the question becomes, what terminals do you use.  If it is only the one you are complaining about, that setting should be enough.  If there are several, find out what $TERM is set to for each, and use a setup like:
case "$TERM" in
    (xterm*) PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$ ' ;;
    (windowsterm) PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$ ' ;;
    (dumb) PS1='\u@\h:\w$ ' ;;
    (*) PS1='\u@\h:\w$ ' ;;
esac

The "*" case is the default...  and "windowsterm" is definitely the wrong value...

It also happens when I only have one SSH open.
PS ft shows 2 lines but not sure how to interpret that. And it also sometime happens with other commands, not all the time though.
echo $PS1 shows a longer format that has the colors coded. I updated the question with the full answers to your question

How do I make the prompt depend on the $TERM variable, and what setting exactly?

@Pineapple29  main problem in text.   PS results: The first line is the shell, the second is the ps.  You do not have two shells running.

The PS1 setting you provided didn't fix it. And I'm not sure I understand case block - where would I put that, exactly? I'm still a Linux newb

It would probably go in ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc    Where/how are you setting PS1 now?  If all else fails, try setting PS1='$ '    If that works try PS1='\u@\h:\w$ ' next.  If those don't work, then you may need your local computer expert to see just what you are doing.   And either way, less is a poor command to test with -- try something that doesn't manipulate the screen, like date or pwd or \ls

The simplest PS1 still doesn't work. And the problem doesn't occur with these other commands that stay on the screen. But anything like man, less, clear etc' causes the issue. And I use those commands alot, especially with piping. I'm the computer expert in my area but just fairly new to in-depth Linux. I know all the basic commands.

If I had to guess there's probably some sort of buffer when the terminal screen refreshes like that after those commands

OK.  As I understand, you are using Microsoft's terminal window as your display...  Honestly, I have no idea what that will show up as, and it always used to give me grief.  I would suggest trying putty from https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/ and using that as your terminal and ssh client.  Either that, or figuring out what $TERM is set to, and trying to find the right setting.  ("ansi" might not be right...)

putty doesn't reprodcue the issue but it doesn't have the nice colors in the prompt. By the way, I also tried Powershell and it has the same issue with double prompt. And the TERM value is "xterm-256color"

if it is about the prompt string printing double, I wonder why it'd only happen intermittently, and also that the prompt has two identical copies of the same string, while in the shown PS1, the other one is slightly different (\u@\h: \w with a space in the middle and no $ at the end)

It seems that terminals on Windows don't understand control sequences when TERM is set to xterm*.
Try :
export TERM=cygwin

Another option is to install Git-bash(https://www.git-scm.com/downloads) and use its ssh.exe.

It does "fix" the double prompt but it changes the behavior of less to not open the output in a separate screen, but rather just print it like cat command. So it's not useful, but at least it shows the root of the issue, I think. What other TERM value can still keep the less function as is?

Try cygwin @Pineapple29

cygwin also turns the less command into a cat command

I tested on my system, cygwin works whereas ansi doesn't. Which terminal are you using ?

I'm using SSH via cmd on windows 10, connecting to a server running Debian 12

In you cmd window, can you show the output of where ssh ?

C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
